# Display loadingwheel during method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, libgdx

I share an image to different social medias, but this process takes a few seconds and can make the user think nothing is happening. So I want to display a loading wheel sort of. I got the animation finished but I can´t work out how to implement it so that it starts spinning when the method is called and stops when it´s finished.

```
btnShare.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            shared = true;
            Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    share();
                }

            });

        }
    });
```

That boolean turning true is the one that calls the spinning wheel to start animation in render method. 
The current event when launching this is the spinning wheel appearing but  freezes untill the method is finished and keeps going after that. And I use Libgdx as you can see so a solution based on their API would be lovely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gdx.app.postRunnable` runs the runnable when the next frame is rendered. It doesn't run it in parallel.

You'll need to create an actual java Thread with your runnable and start that.

Comment: I see. Could you provide me with an example fitting my situation?

Comment: I don't have the bandwidth to do that at the moment. Try putting together some code, then if that doesn't work you can post a new question.